# Permission denied in Ansible synchronize module

Tags: ssh, permissions, sync, rsync, ansible

I'm using Ansible, among other things, for backing up purposes. I run `ansible-playbook` with a **non-root** user (let's say it is `user`) and ssh as `user`. After that, I set up privilege escalation to become `root` on every server. Until now, no problems.

To fetch a remote directory  I have something equivalent to the following rule:

```
- synchronize:
  mode: pull
  delete: true
  src: "{{ dir }}/"
  dest: "{{ tank_base }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}/{{ dir }}/"
  rsync_opts:
    - "--exclude=tmp*"
    - "--exclude=~*"
    - "--exclude=*~"
    - "--exclude=.gvfs/"
    - "--exclude=.cache/"
```

but for some subdirectory it gives the following error (slightly edited to hide personal data):

> fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --delete-after --archive --rsh 'ssh  -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' --exclude=tmp* --exclude=~* --exclude=*~ --exclude=.gvfs/ --exclude=.cache/ --out-format='<>%i %n%L' \"server:/var/backup/\" \"/var/tank/snapshot/server/backup/\"", "failed": true, "msg": "rsync: opendir \"/var/backup/subdir\" failed: Permission denied (13)\nrsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1650) [generator=3.1.2]\n", "rc": 23}

The subdirectory that fails (`/var/backup/subdir` in the above case) is owned by `root:root` and it is readable/writable only by the owner. My guess is `rsync` is trying to pull the files as `user` instead of `root`.

How can I pull those directories without compromising the security and possibly without changing anything on the server side? After all privilege escalation is already in place and working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After all privilege escalation is already in place and working.

Not exactly - `synchronize` module runs `rsync` locally on the management machine, not on the target node (for which you set up the privilege escalation). [Module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html) describes this in details (an excerpt below):

> - The user and permissions for the synchronize `src` are those of the user running the Ansible task on the local host (or the `remote_user` for a `delegate_to` host when `delegate_to` is used).
> - The user and permissions for the synchronize `dest` are those of the `remote_user` on the destination host or the `become_user` if `become=yes` is active.

So it is accessing your source folder (`server:/var/backup/` in the example) as `user` not `root`.

---

If you don't require password for the `user` to `sudo` on the target machine (or just do configure it this way for the `rsync` command) you can use `delegate_to: <your_server>` parameter combined with `rsync_path="sudo rsync"` to run it explicitly with `sudo`.

Comment: I don't know the ansible internals: I was hoping the `sync` module could tunnel its traffic by reusing the already established connection instead of creating a new one. I'll dig more on the `delegate_to` route...

Answer (score 1):

In Ansible 2.2.1.0 this worked for me:

```
- synchronize:
    mode: pull
    src: "/home/vagrant/dir1"
    dest: "/my_linux/dir1"
    recursive: yes
    delete: no
    times: yes
```

...and with this inventory (to use `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` var):

```
[vagrant1]
192.168.77.4

[vagrant1:vars]
ansible_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_private_key_file="/Users/Chilcano/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"
```

Hope it helps you.